# Current Source Dissipating Power or Providing Power?

Tags: circuit-analysis

In my Electric Circuits Analysis class, I came across this problem asking the value of the current sources dissipating power. Here's the diagram I got.
[image]

I'm pretty sure the current source is dissipating power. How did I get this wrong?
In the problem they stated I = 5.

Here's my crude but sufficient work
[image]

Comment: I think there may be some significant syntax/grammar/language issues here. The phrase "absorbed by the...source **to the rest of the circuit**" makes no sense to me. Also, you use the word "dissipated" but the problem uses "absorbed"...do those mean the same thing to you or not?

Comment: Yes, my instructor preferred the word dissipate than absorbed. Also this was from McGraw Hills Connect online homework and we've ran into several typos and errors in the system.

Comment: Maybe they want -20W? (I did the problem myself and also got 20W)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done the numerical part of the calculation correctly.

The current sources sum to 4A, which gives a terminal voltage of 10v on the resistors. Therefore, taking into account the direction of current at each component, the power flow at each component is

5A - generating 50W
1A - generating 10W
2A - dissipating 20W
5ohms - dissipating 20W each

Whether the sign of the final answer is correct depends on what sign convention has been established for the question.

`the power absorbed to the rest of the circuit` is garbled nonsense, so it's anybody's guess.

Comment: V^2/R gives 20W per resistor and the 1A source is generating 10W.

Comment: @immibis duh! Thanks. I'm glad somebody is awake at this time in the morning.

Comment: Thanks yall, my instructor also agreed with the terrible use of the language. He decided that the homework systems answer was wrong and awarded credit for those who missed the question by answering 20 W.